# Using JPA, how can I create a generated column with a regex on an H2 DB?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, h2

We use Liquibase for most environments, but we use JPA annotations to set up H2 locally and for unit tests.

I'm working on adding a generated column, but it's not creating the column and throws no error.
The annotation I'm using works fine for the DEFAULT column, but the GENERATED column (`unique_name`) is straight up ignored. No error, warning or info message.

If i update the application properties configs to show JPA SQL, it just doesn't have the field.

If I try to use DEFAULT instead of GENERATED, it says it can't see the name column:

```
Column "NAME" not found; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE security_markings.security_marking
  ADD COLUMN unique_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT REGEXP_REPLACE(lower(name), '[^a-z0-9]+', '-', 'g') UNIQUE [42122-212] 42S22/42122
```

However, when I add the column manually, via the H2 console, it works fine:

```
ALTER TABLE security_markings.security_marking
  ADD COLUMN unique_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS (REGEXP_REPLACE(lower(name), '[^a-z0-9]+', '-', 'g')) UNIQUE;
```

Entity:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Table(name = "table_name", schema = "schema_name")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class TableName extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false, insertable = false, unique = true, columnDefinition = "UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT random_uuid() UNIQUE")
    private UUID id; //NOTE: This is not the primary key yet, but will be at a future date.

    // FIXME - This is the column that is being ignored.
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false, insertable = false, unique = true, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS (REGEXP_REPLACE(lower(name), '[^a-z0-9]+', '-', 'g')) UNIQUE")
    private String unique_name;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @NotEmpty(message = "Name is required")
    @NaturalId
    private String name;
```

Please note, I am using v2.1.212 of H2 and 2.5.4 of Spring-Boot:

```
<properties>
    <h2.version>2.1.212</h2.version>
    <spring-boot.version>2.5.4</spring-boot.version>
</properties>
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was a copy/paste error.

Both fields had the same column name definded in the JPA annotation. Once I updated the name from `id` to `unique_name`. Issue was solved.

```java
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false, insertable = false, unique = true, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS (REGEXP_REPLACE(lower(name), '[^a-z0-9]+', '-', 'g')) UNIQUE")
    private String unique_name;
```

becomes

```java
    @Column(name = "unique_name", updatable = false, nullable = false, insertable = false, unique = true, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS (REGEXP_REPLACE(lower(name), '[^a-z0-9]+', '-', 'g')) UNIQUE")
    private String uniqueName;
```